# Como usar um Alert sem dar Refresh na Página?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlet, alert

Então, estou fazendo um cadastro de cliente com Java web (jsp) e Servlet, onde recebo no meu servlet de cadastro os dados do formulário e verifico se já existe cpf. O código segue logo abaixo.

```
try {

                String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
                String cpf = request.getParameter("cpf");
                String telefone = request.getParameter("telefone");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                String senha = request.getParameter("senha");
                String cep = request.getParameter("cep");
                String cidade = request.getParameter("cidade");
                String uf = request.getParameter("uf");
                String bairro = request.getParameter("bairro");
                String endereco = request.getParameter("endereco");
                String complemento = request.getParameter("complemento");
                int numero = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));

                Cliente c = new Cliente();
                c.setNome(nome);
                c.setCpf(cpf);
                c.setTelefone(telefone);
                c.setEmail(email);
                c.setSenha(senha);
                c.setCep(cep);
                c.setCidade(cidade);
                c.setUf(uf);
                c.setBairro(bairro);
                c.setEndereco(endereco);
                c.setComplemento(complemento);
                c.setNumero(numero);

                ClienteDAO cDAO = new ClienteDAO();
                Cliente c2 = new Cliente();
                c2 = cDAO.carregaPorCpf(cpf);

                if (!c.getCpf().equals(c2.getCpf())) {
                    cDAO.inserir(c);
                    
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                } else {
                    out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                    out.println("alert('CPF já cadastrado !')");
                    out.println("window.open('form_autocadastrar_cliente.jsp','_self')";);
                    out.println("</script>");
                }

} catch (Exception e) {
   out.print("Erro: " + e);
}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente mas meu único problema e esse  `out.println("window.open('form_autocadastrar_cliente.jsp','_self')";)`;
que após clicar em OK, na mensagem do alert, ele da refresh na página e reseta todos os dados do formulário.

É possível fazer o direcionamento sem dar refresh?

Answer (score -3):

Pesquisando aqui consegui uma forma de não resetar o formulário
ao invés de `window.open('formulario')` usei o `history.back('formulario')`.

```
out.println("history.back('form_autocadastrar_cliente.jsp','_self');");
```

Comment: Não é assim que se faz isso, o que fez é uma gambiarra. Use o local storage para armazenar e resgatar os dados do cadastro quando necessário.

Comment: na verdade funcionou muito bem e a unica gambira que fiz ai foi colocar link no history.back que não precisa. entao ficou assim out.println("history.back();");